# Change index of specific char of NSString

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring

I have a string, for example "Soccer". Now I want to move every "e" by lets say 2 indexes(right word?), so my string looks like this = "erSocc". This has to work with whitespace and negative/- indexes.

I came a cross with this, not perfect working, solution:

```
NSString* text = @"Soccer";
NSString* sign = @"c";
int index = 1;

NSMutableArray* arrayText = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
NSMutableArray* arraySignNewPosition = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
NSMutableArray* arrayOldSignPosition = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

for(int i=0;i<(text.length);i++)
{
    [arrayText addObject:[text substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(i, 1)]];

    if ([[arrayText objectAtIndex:i]isEqualToString:sign])
    {
        [arrayOldSignPosition addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:i]];

        if ((i+index)>(text.length-1))
        {
            int indexDifference = (i+index)-(text.length);
            [arraySignNewPosition addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:indexDifference]];

        }
        else
        {
            [arraySignNewPosition addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:(i+index)]];

        }
    }
}


for (NSNumber* number in arraySignNewPosition)
{
    [arrayText insertObject:sign atIndex:number.integerValue];

    if(number.integerValue-index>0)
    {
        [arrayText removeObjectAtIndex:(number.integerValue-index)];
    }
    else
    {
        [arrayText removeObjectAtIndex:((arrayText.count-1)+(number.integerValue-index))];
    }
}
```

I know the code is not working perfectly, but I would like to know if this is the right way or if there are some Cocoa functions I could use to accomplish my goal. Thanks for your time.

Comment: looks like bits shift but for string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're really just getting substrings and moving them around, so you could do something like this:

```
- (NSString *)shiftRight:(NSUInteger)places
{
    NSAssert(places > 0, @"places must be greater than 0");
    NSAssert(places < [self length], @"places must be less than the length of the string");

    places = [self length] - places;
    NSString *start = [self substringFromIndex:places];
    NSString *end = [self substringToIndex:places];

    return [start stringByAppendingString:end];
}
```

Here's a [complete code listing](https://gist.github.com/mdippery/9772228), with examples.